# Keeping Mercurial branch up to date is removing files I've added

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, branching-and-merging

main branch: `default`

feature branch: `feature`

If the development of a feature I'm implementing in the `feature` branch is taking a while, I'd like to keep this branch up to date with the development that is occurring on the `default` branch to make sure that when my feature is fully implemented, the merging process of `feature` INTO `default` will be as seamless as possible.

Usually this is a no brainer and used to not have an issue.  But now I've noticed that if these `feature` branch(es) have new files added to them, then when I try to merge the head of `default` INTO `feature`, this removes the files I've added in the `feature` branch.

### STEPS I FOLLOWED:

I'm using TortoiseHG Workbench

1. commit and push to new branch `feature` with initial work on feature (new files were added)
2. update to `default` branch to begin work on P1 bugfix
3. make bug fix, commit and push to `default`
4. Update to `feature` branch.
5. Right-click on head of `default` branch, and select 'Merge with local...'
6. click 'Tool Merge' to handle merge conflicts if they pop up (sometimes I need to handle these conflicts manually, sometimes not)
7. Reload my projects in Visual Studio 2013, and the references to the new classes and resource files are unresolved with those files missing.

If there are any merge conflicts that I do have to manually fix, the files that are being removed are never ones identified as having a merge conflict.

### QUESTION:

Should merging the main branch into a feature branch ever remove files only because the main branch doesn't know about them?  Intuitively, I've always assumed that just because the main branch doesn't know about the new files in the feature branch, it won't go through and clean them out.  But this is exactly what is happening.  Does anyone know of a setting that I may have turned on/off that could be causing this behavior?

Comment: That should never happen. And never happened to me. Could you add to your question a minimal sequence of commands to reproduce this problem (e.g. hg branch, hg add, hg commit, and then hg merge after which the file disappear)?

Comment: `hg init; touch oldfile; hg addremove; hg commit -m "oldfile"; hg branch feature; touch newfile; hg addremove; hg commit -m "newfile"; hg checkout default; echo Changes >> oldfile; hg commit -m "Changes"; hg checkout feature; hg merge default; ls` gives `newfile oldfile`. Nothing is removed.

Comment: I'm sure that if I was in a situation as simple as that, then it wouldn't remove any files.  I have updated my questions with the steps I followed

Comment: Do you keep Visual Studio open while updating back and forth?

Comment: I do.  Should I avoid that?  Another thing to point out is that the merge notes that tortoisehg workbench gives says it hasn't removed any files.

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference either, but this doesn't happen every single time, just most of the time.  If I strip the merge changeset and attempt it a few more times, it may not fail so miserably.  It is starting to sound like Visual Studio may be the culprit...

Comment: Well, I don't know how VS reacts to files being disappearing and reappearing. At least it might be worth to try closing VS before update & merge to rule this out. Another possibility would be that the merge overwrites some VS project file which lists your new files in the `feature` branch, and the files are not removed, but VS doesn't know about them (do the new files actually exist in filesystem after the merge?).

Comment: Those are good points.  I stripped the merge changeset out twice and the third time I attempted this merge, things went smoothly (with VS open).  But along those lines, I've also noticed Mercurial not always merging .csproj files correctly.  Sometimes we'll get omitted references to files or even duplicate references to files.

Comment: From your last comment, is it the case that the files disappear, or simply you lose the references to them from the .csproj file?

Comment: I'll have to wait until next merge to verify this, but I'm pretty sure they were gone.  Visual Studio was set to 'Show All Files' and they weren't there when I looked the first time.